# Insert custom data to JSON serialized from DataModel

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have data model class that I'm serializing to JSON in order to be able post serialized JSON to web service. Data model look like this:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
namespace WebCrawler.Models {
    [JsonObject(MemberSerialization.OptIn)]
    public class LinkDataViewModel
    {
        [JsonProperty]
        public string Title { get; set; }
        .....
        [JsonProperty]
        public string CustomerID { get; set; }
    }
}
```

How should I change data model class to be serialized JSON look like that:

```
{"PostPropertyRequest": {SerializedDataModel}}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
[JsonObject(MemberSerialization.OptIn)]
public class MyModel
{
   [JsonProperty]
    public LinkDataViewModel PostPropertyRequest{ get; set; }
}
```

Create above model and serialize that.

```
   MyModel model = new MyModel();
   model.PostPropertyRequest = your model.
```

Now serialize model.

Comment: Thanks for the advise but I can't get how to use it in query var a = (from b in _db.LinkData
                         select new LinkDataViewModel
                         {
                             Title = b.Title,
                             ....
                             CustomerID = b.CustomerID
                         }).Take(10);

Comment: You are mixing two things for using it in a Linq query, it just needs to be an IEnumerable<T> type. That would have nothing to do with Json serialization

Answer (score 1):

you can write your custom json in this way (make your class derived from JsonConverter and override 3 methods)

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
namespace WebCrawler.Models {
    [JsonObject(MemberSerialization.OptIn)]
    public class LinkDataViewModel : JsonConverter
    {
        [JsonProperty]
        public string Title { get; set; }
        .....
        [JsonProperty]
        public string CustomerID { get; set; }

        public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue,            JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
           throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
           if (value == null)
           {
             serializer.Serialize(writer, null);
             return;
            }      
            var properties = value.GetType().GetProperties();
            writer.WriteStartObject();
            //your custom property
            writer.WritePropertyName("PostPropertyRequest");
            writer.WriteStartObject();
            foreach (var property in properties)
            {
              // write property name
              writer.WritePropertyName(property.Name);
              serializer.Serialize(writer, property.GetValue(value, null));
            }
            writer.WriteEndObject();
            writer.WriteEndObject();
        }
    }
}
```

refer this nice [article](http://blog.maskalik.com/asp-net/json-net-implement-custom-serialization/) for documentation

Comment: There's no need for custom serializer for the current query, default serializer will simply do the job

Comment: @MrinalKamboj the OP doesn't have a class wrapper

Comment: how difficult is to create a wrapper, I too create custom serializer, but only when I want the values to modified / calculated or they need a prefix / suffix

Comment: @MrinalKamboj maybe the OP can't change the classes or the structure. I have suggest my solution without adding new classes, I know that with a class wrapper you can achieve the goal. StackOverflow is great because there are so many opinions :)

Comment: Agreed within the constraints you have suggested :)

Answer (score 1):

For Json it is important to understand the unlike XML it doesn't have a root element, you current Json generated is:

```
{
    "Title": "Value",
    "CustomerID": "Value"
}
```

What you need is:

```
{
"PostPropertyRequest":
                  {
                    "Title": "Value",
                    "CustomerID": "Value"
                  }
}
```

You need to simply wrap your current class, apply Json Property and serialize:

```
[JsonObject(MemberSerialization.OptIn)]
public class LinkDataViewModelWrapper
{
   [JsonProperty("PostPropertyRequest")]
    public LinkDataViewModel LinkDataViewObj{ get; set; }
}
```

Now you need to serialize LinkDataViewModelWrapper, after initializing various elements and properties